# EDA and Data cleaning can be done before selecting data samples from population?

Tags: sampling, population, data-preprocessing, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a huge dataset from which I need to select a sample for machine learning. The data set has high NAN and noise. Hence is it good approach to do EDA, cleaning before taking samples?